# View new item form but can't view all item

Tags: list

I want everyone can add new item to the list. But can't view the list items or the all item page. 
There is two choice that I find but can't did.

First, I won't share the all item page with everybody just share with the admin group.

Second, I try to remove the link list name at the new Form page. 
But I couldn't did them. For the first choice the permissions are depends eachothers. So the second choice is much easier than the first one.

How can I remove the title of the list name?

Answer (score 0):

In the list settings (advanced settings) you can set it to only allow users to view items they submitted.  When this is configured, only people who have permissions to manage the list would be able to see all submissions.

Alternatively you can use a workflow to remove user permissions on the item when it is submitted.